# rename a column's child names s"${col.name}.*" in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Following code is used to extract child dataframe of a given parent column.

```
mdf.selectExpr(mdf.schema.map(c => if(c.dataType.typeName =="struct") s"${c.name}.*" else c.name):_*)
```

how do we rename column name with following pattern ( parent_column_name + "_" + child_column_name )

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, Row}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
    implicit class DFHelper(inDF: DataFrame) {
      import inDF.sparkSession.implicits._
      def fromJson(columns:Column*):DataFrame = {
        val schemas = columns.map(column => (column, inDF.sparkSession.read.json(inDF.select(column).as[String]).schema))
        val mdf = schemas.foldLeft(inDF)((df,schema) => {
                df.withColumn(schema._1.toString(),from_json(schema._1,schema._2))
        })        
        mdf.selectExpr(mdf.schema.map(c => if(c.dataType.typeName =="struct") s"${c.name}.*" else c.name):_*)
      }
    }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
defined class DFHelper
```

Above is the dynamically generated schema for any dataframe.

Comment: Your question is too vague. If you want to rename column A to column B, you can do `df.withColumnRenamed("A", "B")`. If you want to make a name from variable expression `(( parent_column_name + "_" + child_column_name ))` then you can use `s"$parent_column_name_$child_column_name"`

Comment: mdf is a dynamically generated table . Please see the updated description @SamirVyas